# Page break occuring despite CSS to prevent it

Tags: html, css

In a document I attempt to export as a PDF, there is a table of comments. The table consists of a few rows, the first row displaying the author, the second row displaying the comment. The comment row consists of a single cell that is pre-wrapper to maintain whitespace, and contains

elements for each line of text or 
 elements for spaces.

Whenever the comment row extends past the bottom of a page, the page breaks and pushes the entire row to the next page, despite my css being as follows

```
table {
    page-break-inside: auto;

    tbody {
        page-break-inside: auto;

        .comment-author {
            page-break-after: avoid;
        }

        .comment-content {
            page-break-before: avoid;
            page-break-inside: auto;

            p {
                page-break-inside: auto;
            }

            br {
                page-break-inside: auto;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone explain what I may be doing incorrectly?

Upon request, HTML is like:

```
<table>
    <thead/>
    <tbody>
        <tr className="comment-author">
            <td>John Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr className="comment-content">
            <td>
                <p>This would be the first line of text</p>
                <br/>
                <p>This would be the second line of text</p>
                // Etc for full comment content until last line
                // Designed to never end with a <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: post your html code (sample atleast ) which you are trying to print.

Comment: Html snippet of code included into original post

Comment: Are you feeding the CSS through a preprocessor?

Comment: Yes, I believe SASS

Comment: You believe? You're the one running the code, yes?

Comment: Yep, but I'm still pretty new to designing websites in react using webpack bundles and loaders, and all the new terms can be overwhelming at times, I apologise for my inexperience.

Comment: @Alister i checked your code in my codepen. i don't see a problem in the print preview output. here is my codepen link https://codepen.io/Divine1/pen/RMVYLX

Comment: Okay thanks for your help. I guess it's something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ended up removing the table and use divs instead. This meaning additional CSS including `display: table-cell` for a consistent design.